# array_keys() with normal array in its parameter

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
$arr = array("value1", "value2", "value3");
$array_with_keys = array_keys($arr);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array_with_keys);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

This is an example of `array_keys()` that have non-associative array in its parameter. So no keys.

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
```

Why is the output this? I searched the manual and I can't find a example of array_keys() with normal array in its parameter.

So can some explain why the output is this?

Common sense tells me that it's because in a normal array the key is its index, which is `0`, `1`, `2`.

Comment: "normal" array keys start at 0, not at 1.... and this is extensively documented in the PHP docs

Comment: I edited it 0,1,2 ..... why it changed back to 1,2,3

Comment: What else did you expect? Arrays in PHP are zero based. What are "normal" arrays?

Comment: Looks like @user569711 edited this question and changed 0,1,2 to 1,2,3 about 4 minutes after it was posted

Comment: @MarkBaker - I don't think I edited the code, so that might have been in the original post. I just edited the post itself. My apologies!

Answer (score 1):

All arrays are actually associative arrays in PHP.
Even if you don't declare them:

```
$arr = array("value1", "value2", "value3");
```

This is the same as

```
$arr = array(0 => "value1", 1 => "value2", 2 => "value3");
```

So PHP automatically adds keys for you.

Comment: @PeeHaa I've written confusing and senseless stuff (`$arr == array_keys(array_flip($arr))`). You're absolutely right ;) Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

Your common sense is correct. When you create an array without keys, it is numerically indexed. When you do an `array_keys` on such an array, the numeric keys are getting extracted.